# How to extend an IIS request - Django

Tags: python, django, iis, server, request

How can I extend the waiting time for e.g. downloading a file? I use **ISS** and tried to change the **Request Timeout** from 90 to 300 in **FastCGI Settings**, but that didn't help. If the file download request takes longer than 90 seconds, I have a 500 error. The entire site is based on python / Django.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis First learn where that 500 error came from.

Comment: I know where this error came from. I summoned him on purpose by waiting a long time. I want to know how can I extend this time on the server?

Comment: "I know where this error came from", then why not edit your question to include that? You are hosting Python on IIS, so the situation is not much different from PHP on IIS, https://blog.lextudio.com/who-should-be-contacted-for-php-on-iis-issues-c80b90bd365 But many PHP developers usually have no idea what component is the culprit, and hope you are not doing the same here. There are tons of timeout settings on each of the components, so knowing the culprit is the key here.

Comment: I don't think I fully understand you and it is possible that I didn't say enough about it. Error 500 now arises mainly because I caused it on purpose using time.sleep (120) in the function. Mainly to determine what is the maximum waiting time and it is 90s and I would like to increase 90s only to 150 and then everything will be ok.

Comment: Do you want to increase request timeout in IIS? if so, you can follow this steps: right click on the site and go to Manage Web Site -> Advanced Settings. Under Connection Limits option, you should see Connection Time-out.

Comment: I have no such options.

Comment: What do you mean?